# expected a class or namespace

Tags: c++

I am getting a compile time for an enum in C++ , the error says Expected a class or namespace

```
  mf.setStatus(MediaFile::SyncStatus::Synced);
```

The enum is defined like this

```
 class MediaFile
 {
    public:
    enum SyncStatus 
    {
        New = 0,
        Remove = 5,
        Synced = 10,
        Unknown = 15
    };

    //...
 };
```

I am compiling in xcode but I guess it has to do with C++ syntax, previously it compiled fine on Visual studio. Visual studio probably gave some warnings about it, but did the build
Any suggestions please ?

Comment: You're missing a semicolon at the end of your class declaration. Since you say this compiled under VS, this must simply be a typo in your question ;-)

Comment: yes, just a typo, actual class is a bit more complex :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try `MediaFile::Synced` instead. `SyncStatus` is a type name (as in `SyncStatus theStatus`), not a namespace.

Comment: +1. Note that C++11 allows `MediaFile::SyncStatus::...` though.

Comment: Thanks, @Cameron, I had no idea.

Answer (score 4):

`enum`s in C++ do not define a namespace, so the values of the enumerator go into the surrounding context. You need to do `MediaFile::Synced` instead.