# Getting "expected a class or namespace"

Tags: c++, stdvector

I've decided to take up C++ after nearly a decade of not messing with it, and I'm having an issue with some code, and having some great difficulty understanding what's wrong.  I've seen several questions that are related, [expected a class or namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14656360/expected-a-class-or-namespace) and [Expected a class or namespace; syntax is proper and correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19237487/expected-a-class-or-namespace-syntax-is-proper-and-correct). as well as spending hours trying to research other ones, and i still can't figure this out.

**mainwindow.hpp**

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    std::vector<Card> cards;

    // Events:
public slots:
    void shuffle();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow) {

    ...

    // Spades
    cards.push_back(Card(Suit::SPADES, Value::ACE)); // <- getting the errors here
    cards.push_back(Card(Suit::SPADES, Value::TWO)); // <-
}
```

*the `Card` class just has a ctor with `Suit suit, Value value` which comes from another file.*

I'm having difficulty understanding why i'm getting this error:

```
expected a class or namespace
   cards.push_back(Card(Suit::SPADES, Value::ACE));
                ^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've figured out what you're doing wrong :)

What you were supposed to post is *exactly* the code below, less the correct section. That's all that we need to see to diagnose the issue. Your issue has nothing to do with Qt, etc. Really: minimization is the key. It saves *everyone's* time. Yours and ours.

```
#include <vector>

enum Suit { SPADES };
enum Value { ACE, TWO };

class Card {
public:
   Card(Suit, Value) {}
};

int main()
{
   std::vector<Card> cards;
   // Correct
   cards.push_back(Card(SPADES, ACE));
   cards.push_back(Card(SPADES, TWO));
   // Wrong since Suit and Value are not classes nor namespaces,
   // they are merely enum tags.
   cards.push_back(Card(Suit::SPADES, Value::ACE));
   cards.push_back(Card(Suit::SPADES, Value::TWO));
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: also thanks for the hint about what's really needed.. lower level you go, the more code you need to show.. ;)

Comment: Oh, that's the C# enum idiom (more or less) :-).